# Pattern match on /xxx/xxx/xxx

Tags: regex, perl

I have

```
$w="/fold1/fold2/qwerty.h"
```

I want to cut /qwerty.h and get /fold1/fold2

I tried

```
$w=~s/\/.+\.h\z//; and $w=~s/\/.+?\.h\z//;
```

but those remove whole string.

```
$w=~s/\/\w+\.h\z//;
```

works but  suppose I have qwe\rty.h instead of qwerty.h. That won't work again.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html

Comment: Can you use the File::Basename module?

Comment: When dealing with patterns that contain a slash, I like to switch to using {} to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome#Pattern_example).  Thus `m/foo\/bar/` would become `m{foo/bar}`.  Likewise `s/foo\/bar/qux\/baz/` would become `s{foo/bar}{qux/baz}`.  This can be most anything: `m!foo! is also allowed.  If the delimiter is part of an open/close pair, that pair is used.  This is documented at [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Simple-word-matching).

Comment: Using File::Basename is the right answer, but remember when using regexes that need slashes that you can use other delimiters. For example, `s{/[^/]+\.h\z}{}` is clearer than `s/\/[^\/]+\.h\z//`.

Comment: and how about `rindex($str,'/')` and `substr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing; you want to remove after the final `/`, so your pattern should be based on `/`, not "any character" (`.`) or "word characters" (`\w`)

```
$w =~ s/\/[^\/]+\.h\z//;
```

which is more cleanly written by avoiding `/` as regex separator:

```
$w =~ s,/[^/]+\.h\z,,;
```

That said, `File::Basename` is a cleaner and more generally portable solution.

Comment: `[]` is a character class, a group of characters any of which can match (or, with leading `^` as here, match any character *except* those specified).  So here we match any character that is not a `/`.

Answer (score 7):

Use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), one of the modules in the Standard Library:

```
 use File::Basename;
 my $dir = dirname( $path );
```

In general, when you know that data are a certain type, try to treat them as that type. In this case, you know it's a file path, so instead of treating it like a general string, treat it like a file path.

Answer (score 0):

If [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename) doesn't work for you, then you can do something like this:

```
substr( $w, 0, rindex( $w, '/' ))
```

I use this so often that I have several idioms around this:

```
sub rpos_of {
    return unless 1 + ( my $pos = rindex( $_[0], $_[1] )); 
    return $pos || '0E0';
}
sub before_last { 
    return $_[0] unless my $pos = &rpos_of;
    return substr( $_[0], 0, $pos );
}
sub after_last  { 
    return $_[0] unless my $pos = &rpos_of;
    return substr( $_[0], $pos + length( $_[1] )); 
}
sub break_at_last { 
    return $_[0] unless my $pos = &rpos_of;
    return ( substr( $_[0], 0, $pos )
           , substr( $_[0], $pos + length( $_[1] ))
           );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$w=~s#(.*)/[^/]+#\1#
```

this also works , just find the final / , and substitute the whole string with the substring before the final /